# How to make windows resist overlapping each other?

Tags: unity, compiz

I just upgraded from Lucid / Gnome2 to Precise / Unity.  In Gnome2, if you try to drag one window next to another one, there is a pause* when their edges meet so that you can align them perfectly.  What is that behaviour called?  Can I get it in Unity?

* The window stops moving once its border touches the border of another window, even as the mouse continues to move.  After the mouse has moved maybe 5-10 more pixels, the window resumes moving along with the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, install [compizconfig-settings-manager (CCSM) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run it and go to the `Window Management` Plugins:

[image: CCSM window management plugin]

Choose `Snapping Windows`, choose `Behaviour` Tab and then activate `Window Edges`.

[image: Window edges]

Play with the settings as you like.